# Invoke-DscResource on WindowsFeatureSet fails

Tags: dsc

Invoking Invoke-DSCResource on WindowsFeatureSet fails with strange error.

```ps1
Invoke-DscResource -Name WindowsFeatureSet -Property @{Name = 'FileAndStorage'; Ensure = 'Present' } -Method test -ModuleName PSDesiredStateConfiguration
```

> Invoke-DscResource : Failed to serialize properties into CimInstance.
>   At line:5 char:1
>   + Invoke-DscResource -Name WindowsFeatureSet -Property @{Name = 'FileAn ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-DscResource], SerializationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException,Microsoft.PowerShell.DesiredStateConfiguration.Commands.InvokeDscResourceMethodCommand

Comment: This is a known issue and at this point of time i am not aware of any workarounds other than using the resource from the configuration itself.

Comment: I see you have already filed [an issue](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/13744065-invoke-dscresource-on-windowsfeatureset-fails) on PowerShell User Voice and noted that it seems to affect all composite resources.  Others should vote for the issue if you would like it fixed.

Comment: Unfortunately workaround is not going to work for dsc_resource in Chef since they rely on Invoke-DSCResource cmdlet for operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue.  There is [an issue](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/13744065-invoke-dscresource-on-windowsfeatureset-fails) filed in PowerShell User Voice, which is marked as 'Survey'.  'Survey' indicates 'We saw this and we are considering it...' per the [PowerShell User Voice Home Page](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell).

This is also documented in [Chef Discourse here](https://discourse.chef.io/t/dsc-resource-will-not-work-with-composite-resources/8443).

And there is an issue open to update the Chef Documentation [here] (https://github.com/chef/chef-web-docs/issues/59) and DSC Documentation [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/361).

Answer (score 1):

Composite configurations are never loaded by the LCM. They are only used during compilation and the generated mof has the composite configuration resolved to its underlying resources. So this isn't expected to work. You can try using 'WindowsFeature' instead. This blog explains composite resources in DSC http://nanalakshmanan.com/blog/Composite-Resources-Explained/